# How to wrap JS library which creates elements by itself into Vue component with slot?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have vanilla JS library which is given root element and callback function `(data: any) => HTMLElement`. Library calls callback and positions elements within root one.

I want to wrap this library into Vue component with slot to use it like this:

```
<my-component v-slot='data'>
  <div>{{data.field}}</div>
</my-component>
```

Slots returned by `useSlots` are functions which, being called, return virtual DOM. How can I turn this into real DOM element retaining reactivity?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work this way:

```js
const component = defineComponent({
  props: ['data', 'render'],
  render: function() {
    return this.render(this.data)
  },
})
function callback(data: any): Element {
  const elem = document.createElement('div')
  const app = createApp(component, {render: slots.default!, data})
  app.mount(elem);
  return elem
}
```